# Add verbose logging to System.Data.SQLite

Tags: sqlite, ado.net, system.data.sqlite

Is it possible to add verbose logging to System.Data.SQLite ? 
I want to log all db operations such as connection opened/closed and all sql commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can hook into the static `Changed` event on `SQLiteConnection`:

```
SQLiteConnection.Changed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{eventArgs.EventType}: {eventArgs.Text}");
};
```

This will print out lots of information. There are other properties on that `eventArgs` object as well.

Comment: Ooooh, this looks really useful.
Bookmarked. Thanks Lasse!